# Create array of worksheet names dynamially

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to generate the `ws In Worksheets(Array("DiscardedDataFile", "GephiNodeFile", "GephiEdgeFile"))` for the 2nd Sub dynamically?

Edit: Updated with simoco code and my revision

```
Sub SaveSheetsAsNewBooks3()
Dim SheetName As String
Dim MyFilePath As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsN As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Index <> 1 Then
            SheetName = ws.Name
            ws.Copy

            MyFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & SheetName

            If Len(Dir(MyFilePath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                MkDir MyFilePath
            End If

    With ActiveWorkbook
    '~save book in this folder
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=MyFilePath & "\" & SheetName & "_" & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY hh.mm") & ".csv", FileFormat:=6
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

 End With
 End If
 Next ws

Sheets("Source").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, what are you going to achieve? it's little bit unclear to me. Are you going to loop through all sheets except first? As I see, you could just use `For Each ws In Worksheets(ShtNames)` where `ShtNames` defined in first `Sub`

Comment: Sorry about lack of clarity, yes I want to skip the first worksheet.  I am tiring to not have to enter the worksheet names manual for every new project, the number of worksheets and there names will change with every project. Thanks

Comment: if you don't like `For i = 2 To Sheets.count`, you could use `For ws In Worksheets` and inside for each loop add if statement: `If ws.Name<>Worksheets(1).Name Then`

Comment: or even simplier: `If ws.Index<>1 Then`

Comment: Tim your updated code is little bit messy for me, let me add answer with more clear approach.

Comment: I updated both Subs, I am getting error `Type mismatch` at `For Each ws In Worksheets(wsf)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need something like this:

```
Sub SaveSheetsAsNewBooks2()
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim MyFilePath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsN As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            If ws.Index <> 1 Then
                SheetName = ws.Name

                MyFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & SheetName

                If Len(Dir(MyFilePath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                    MkDir MyFilePath
                End If
                'create new workbook
                ws.Copy

                With ActiveWorkbook
                    'save new workbook in this folder
                    .SaveAs fileName:=MyFilePath & "\" & SheetName & "_" & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY hh.mm") & ".csv", FileFormat:=6
                    .Close SaveChanges:=True
                End With
            End If
        Next ws

        .Worksheets(1).Select
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: simoco, thank you. I had to revise what you wrote so that it gave me the output I needed, is what I did a sensible revision of your code? (update my code above)

Comment: @Tim, have you tried my very last code? If I understood your question correctly, it should save each sheet (except first one) in separate csv file.

Comment: simco, I have, it creates a folder called `Sheet1` and in it is a file called `Sheet1.csv`

Comment: Is it what you need or something worng?

Comment: Again sorry for my lack of clarity, I need to create folders with the sheet names and in these folders a is a workbook made from the sheet with that name.

Comment: Tim, I've just tested my code again and it do exactly what you need - it creates new folder for each sheet and in these folders is a csv file made from the sheet with that name. Try please again my very last updated code.

Comment: simoco, I created a new workbook with 4 sheets then inserted a module and placed your code in it then ran it and it worked perfectly.  But in my live workbook the macro only creates a folder called `Sheet1` and a file called `Sheet1.csv` do you have any experience with what might cause this, another piece of code interfering with it?  Thanks

Comment: simoco I figured out what was causing the problem in my live workbook I had to change `With ThisWorkbook` to `With ActiveWorkbook`.  I greatly appriciate all your help, thank you.